# Overlapping Crouton-Toasts?

Tags: android, crouton

I'm using Crouton in Android. If the user is not logged in, an infinite-duration Crouton-Toast is shown on the top of my Activity. The problem is, that If the user receives a chat-message (login not required), this message should show up as a crouton for some seconds as well.

What for options do I have to show both toasts? I would like the idea to "stack" the toasts. So the "not logged in"-Toast is shown on top and if the user receives a message, than this message would be displayed below the other toast. Is this possible? If yes - what do I have to do?

Option 2: Displaying the chat-message and hide the "not logged in" toast. After hiding the chat-message, the logged-in-toast should reappear.

**Why** is the second toast not shown if they both affect the same viewgroup? Shouldn't this toast either replace or hide the other toast?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is currently implemented, only one Crouton can be shown at a time. There is a [pull request](https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton/pull/87), which can not be merged in it's existing form.